# create an instance of a class from a string and then use it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

I am working on a MVC project so in my controller constructor, i am calling one of class (`GetServiceName`) which returns me service name as `string` (service is another class where all the methods gets called by controller).

1. One option is my class `GetServiceName` returns service name and then I initialize that (don't know how to do it)
2. I am doing something like this in my `GetServiceName` class

   ```
   ObjectHandle oh;
   oh = Activator.CreateInstance(null, ClassName);
   return oh;
   ```

Now I get `oh` as object in my controller but how to I initialize it in my controller something like-

`oh _name = new oh();`

(where `oh` is a ObjectHandle returned by GetServiceName class)

and should be able to use `_name` as `_name.getName(id)` where getname is method name is respective service.

I know there are lots of question on stackoverflow related to this, but i cant get my code working by using any of them

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` is correct, though I'm not sure I follow the code correctly. You need the object properly casted--is that the issue?

Comment: `oh _name = (oh)Activator.CreateInstance(null, ClassName);`

Comment: What it sounds like you're doing is a factory pattern. It also sounds like some kind of dependency resolution.

Comment: @sriram: your gives an error ````The type or namespace name 'oh' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)````

Comment: @Romoku: yes, that what it is and perhaps i have no idea if i am doing it right way or on a totally different path.

Comment: You said `oh` is the class name.? It should be  `YourNamespace.oh _name = (YourNamespace.oh)Activator.CreateInstance(null, ClassName);

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: oh is not a classname?(question edited) its an object returned by GetServiceName class. Point no 2 is what i do in GetServiceName class and it returns oh (objecthandle) to controller

Comment: Does `Type.GetType(ClassName)` return a type?

Comment: @valverij: Yes, it return Name and FullName

Comment: Have you tried `var type = Type.GetType(ClassName); oh = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ObjectHandle`?

Comment: @valverij: It all work fine till getting ````oh````, what i am after is once ````oh```` is returned to controller. How can i initilize my class contained in ````oh````.

Comment: Are you attempting to do remoting?  If not, then you probably shouldn't be using any of the `CreateInstance()` methods that return an `ObjectHandle`.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a class instance you should retrieve the object itself from the handle:

```
ObjectHandle oh = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "typeName");
object instance = oh.Unwrap();
```